# Animating image on event

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I have an image with circle inside circle approx 10 circles,each of different color i want to show them one by one on button click from center to outside and on another button click disappear one by one from outer to inner. Is this possible and how?
Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get help from below code i m not wrong and you are looking for radar style animation

```
#import "RadarAnimation.h"

@implementation RadarAnimation

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        [self SetUPAnimation];

        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)SetUPAnimation
{


    [self AddRader];
    double delayInSeconds = 1.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self AddRader];
    });


}

-(void)AddRader
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    //    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    view.frame=self.frame;
    [self setWidth:[Helper currentWidth] ofView:view];
    [self setHeight:[Helper currentWidth] ofView:view];
    [self setXPossitionto:self.frame.size.width/2-view.frame.size.width/2 ofView:view];
    [self setYPossitionto:self.frame.size.height/2-view.frame.size.height/2 ofView:view];


    view.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetHeight(view.frame)/2;
    view.tag=175751;
    int kRingExpansionTime=6.0;

    CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    scaleAnimation.duration = kRingExpansionTime;
    scaleAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
    scaleAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
    scaleAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.8];

    [view.layer addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"scale"];


    // fade out the ring part way thru the animation
    CABasicAnimation* alphaAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    alphaAnim.fromValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.3];
    alphaAnim.toValue     = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1];
    alphaAnim.beginTime   = kRingExpansionTime * 0.7f;      // start part way thru
    alphaAnim.duration    = kRingExpansionTime - alphaAnim.beginTime;

    CAAnimationGroup* group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    group.duration    = kRingExpansionTime;
    group.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;      // repeat forever
    group.animations  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:scaleAnimation,alphaAnim, nil];

    [view.layer addAnimation:group forKey:nil];

    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:135.0/255.0 blue:219.0/255.0 alpha:0.5];
    view.alpha=0.4;
    view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:135.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    //view.center=_VwEmptyplaceholder.center;
    //view.center=CGPointMake(_VwEmptyplaceholder.frame.size.width/2, _VwEmptyplaceholder.frame.size.height/2);
    view.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    view.tag=175751;

    //[self insertSubview:view belowSubview:btn];
}
-(void)setXPossitionto:(CGFloat)xpostion ofView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGRect frame =  view.frame;
    frame.origin.x =  xpostion;
    view.frame=frame;
}

-(void)setYPossitionto:(CGFloat)ypostion ofView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGRect frame =  view.frame;
    frame.origin.y =  ypostion;
    view.frame=frame;
}

-(void)setWidth:(CGFloat)Width ofView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGRect frame =  view.frame;
    frame.size.width =  Width;
    view.frame=frame;
}

-(void)setHeight:(CGFloat)Height ofView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGRect frame =  view.frame;
    frame.size.height =  Height;
    view.frame=frame;
}
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: just in that Helper function seting frame code is there.. @akshay

Comment: Thanks for help but this isn't i want. I have an image with circles inside circles each of different color i want to show them one by one on button click from center to outside and on another button click disappear one by one from outer to inner @parth